# TypeError in Django Application

Tags: python, html, django, typeerror

I am making a Django application. It's a wikipedia page that will allow you to create a new page if you click .

The path is in urlpatterns is:

`path("create", views.create, name="create")`

The function in views.py is:

```
def create(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = Post(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        title = form.cleaned_data["title"]
        textarea = form.cleaned_data["textarea"]
        entries = util.list_entries()
        if title in entries:
            return render(request, "encyclopedia/error.html", {"form": Search(), "message": "Page already exist"})
        else:
            util.save_entry(title,textarea)
            page = util.get_entry(title)
            page_converted = markdowner.convert(page)

            context = {
                'form': Search(),
                'page': page_converted,
                'title': title
            }

            return render(request, "encyclopedia/entry.html", context)
else:
    return render(request, "encyclopedia/create.html", {"form": Search(), "post": Post()})
```

The error message I am getting is:

TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found

Full Traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/franciscogutierrez/Desktop/Software1/CS50W/project1/wiki/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Users/franciscogutierrez/Desktop/Software1/CS50W/project1/wiki/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 179, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/franciscogutierrez/Desktop/Software1/CS50W/project1/wiki/encyclopedia/views.py", line 60, in webpages
"title":markdowner.convert(page)
File "/Users/franciscogutierrez/Desktop/Software1/CS50W/project1/wiki/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/markdown2.py", line 316, in convert
text = unicode(text, 'utf-8')
TypeError: decoding to str: need a bytes-like object, NoneType found

Comment: When the request method is POST and the form is not valid you do not return a response. Views should not return None

Comment: I can't seem to get it to go to the create.html. Every time I click the link "Create a new Page", I get the type error message. In create.html I have a form where it would then allow the user to POST.

Comment: Add the full traceback to your question, it will narrow down the actual issue

Comment: I've updated the question thank you

Answer (score 0):

As the trace shows, you are passing None in the markdowner function while it expects you to send a byte object. You are getting page from your utils.get_entry function. Make sure that do not return None. If that's not possible, check for None values before calling the markdower function. Try it like this -

```
page = util.get_entry(title)
if page:
    page_converted = markdowner.convert(page)
```

Comment: I tried it, it still says type error with " if page: "

Answer (score 0):

Had a str:title path that ran before the "create" path and so create would go in the path above instead of the other path. Fixed it by putting create on top of str:title